# Request specific data in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to show breadcrumbs on my asp.net mvc 4 website. The generation of the breadcrumbs depends upon the context, for example on a forumpage it is determined differently then on a blogpage. on the one hand, there should be one partialview "Breadcrumbs", but then this partialview does not per se know the context. And I don't want to 'pollute' my Viewmodels with breadcrumb stuff. I thought of 2 possible solutions:

1) Make viewmodels derive from a basemodel that contains the breadcrumbdata and in the views the partialview "Breadcrumbs" can be called with given ViewModel as Model.
2) In the actions save the breadcrumbdata somewhere (in webforms we had HttpContext.Items for example) where the partialview "Breadcrumbs" can read them.

But I am not very pleased with both of these options. Are there more elegant ways to achieve this?

Comment: Why are you not pleased with the first option you mention.  This would appear to be a pretty clean implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The partial view for the breadcrumbs should be given the context (as a model, probably a list of breadcrumbs with text and URLs).

If we assume each view knows its breadcrumbs, you can just pass the breadcrumb data from the view to the partial view:

If you render the breadcrumbs in a layout page, the view should pass the breadcrumb data to the layout page. I'd use the `ViewBag` for that.

So, here's how I'd do it (if the breadcrumbs are not very deep and are relatively stable):

**SomeView.cshtml**

```
ViewBag.Breadcrumbs = new List<Breadcrmb>() {
          new Breadcrumb(){ Title = "Home", Url = Url.Action("Index", "Home") },
          new Breadcrumb(){ Title = TopicModel.Forum.Title,
                            Url = Url.Action("Forum",
                                             new { id = TopicModel.ForumId }) },
          new Breadcrumb(){ Title = TopicModel.Title,
                            Url = Url.Action("ViewTopic",
                                             new { id = TopicModel.Id }) }
};
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
@Html.RenderPartial( "_Breadcrumbs", ViewBag.Breadcrumbs )
```

**_Breadcrumbs.cshtml**

```
@Model IEnumerable<Breadcrumb>

@* Render breadcrumbs *@
```

The breadcrumb data could be generated in a more flexible way but you didn't ask about that so I'm not going to go deeper on that part. Suffice to say getting the parent list of breadcrumbs for a view and then just adding your own would be better.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly use Session if session state is enabled.

the in your view you could get your session data

```
@{
    var breadcrumbs = (BreadCrumbsCastHere)@Session["breadcrumbs"];
}
```

Comment: Also... There is a Context that is in [System.Web.Mvc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.webviewpage.context(v=vs.98).aspx) namespace it contains an Items key value pair Dictionary. You might look into that if your used to HttpContext from WebForms.

Comment: imho, this is *not* a better option than #1 in op.  It introduces state, which should be avoided if possible.